# Как настроить composer для git submodule с двумя laravel проектами?

Tags: git, composer

Есть 2 laravel проекта, один - игра, второй - игровая платформа, в которой хранятся основные данные. Мне нужно к игре подключить платформу сабмодулем. По [документации](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-Git-%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B8) выполнил `git submodule add https://github.com/chaconinc/DbConnector`, в корне появилась папка склонированного сабмодуля. В `composer.json` добавил в секцию `psr-4`:

```
    "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Platform\\": "./GamePlatformBack/app/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
```

Далее выполнил `composer dumpautoload -o`.
Ожидаю, что классы подмудуля будут доступны через namespace `Platform\...`, но классы недоступны. Порылся в автозагрузчике composer - там есть упоминание     `'Platform\\' => array($baseDir . '/GamePlatformBack/app'),`, но доступа к классам не появляется. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Каталог `GamePlatformBack` - это и есть сабмодуль? Попробуйте так `"Platform\\": "GamePlatformBack/app/Platform"`, затем `composer dump`.

Comment: @TotalPusher, да, это и есть сабмодуль. Я пробовал в psr-4 и так и эдак прописывать - не работает. Также я пробовал GamePlatformBack/app/ добавлять в `classmap`, композер классы подхватил, много ругался на дубликаты классов (например App\User есть и на платформе и на игре), но в коде все равно доступа к этим классам (даже уникальным на платформе) нет.

Comment: 1. Войдите в каталог где composer.json проекта (не сабмодуля). Ожидаю, что `ls ./GamePlatformBack/app/Platform` выведет список файлов-классов платформы. 2. Если пункт 1 с ошибкой, покажите структуру каталогов хотя бы через `tree -L 3`, чтобы были понятны пути. 3. `ругался на дубликаты классов` - через композер вы сможете подключить неймспейс GamePlatformBack, но вот если в нем используется `App\User`, то будет использован не платформенный класс, а тот, что в проекте. 4. Вообще у вас странная идея включить платформу сабмодулем. Правильно - изготовить для платформы пакет, который и использовать

Comment: @TotalPusher, да, спасибо, неймспейсы действительно должны быть разные. В итоге проблему решили переписав код, без пакетов.